# Visual Studio Code. Build gulp task has no effect. Nothing happens, output is empty

Tags: gulp, visual-studio-code

I am trying to run build task in VS Code. Unfortunately, nothing happens when I attempt to execute the task from the task runner or with a hot-key combo (shift+ctrl+b). The OUTPUT window (with tasks dropdown) is empty.

My **task.json** file content:

```
{"version": "0.1.0",
"command": "gulp",
"isShellCommand": true,
"tasks": [
    {
        "taskName": "deploy",
        "isBuildCommand": true,
        "showOutput": "always"
}]}
```

My **gulpfile.js** is on root application folder

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var plugins = require("gulp-load-plugins")();
var karma = require("karma");

function getTask()
{
    var srvInst = new karma.Server({
        configFile: __dirname + "/karma.conf.js",
    });
  return  srvInst.start();
}

//build task
gulp.task("deploy",function(){
    plugins.util.log("done");
});

//test task
gulp.task("test",getTask());
```

This is simplified versions of files, but the problem remains. I'm wondering why the OUTPUT is empty. Where can I find any clue what is wrong?

Comment: Have you tried moving your `isShellCommand` within your `deploy` task? When I run a task with it outside of the task it doesn't work. If I move it within the task it does work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to find the cause of the problem. It is possible to debug gulp task with help of node debugger and I find out that it is `gulp.task("test",getTask());` playing tricks on me and on OUTPUT. Even if I execute build command, the getTask function is called because of mistaken execution getTask().

The question now is following - empty OUTPUT is a bug or a feature in such context. Should I report about it or it is totally my fault?